# scale bar and north arrow in rasterVis plot in R

Tags: r, r-raster, raster-graphics, rastervis

I am using rasterVis package in R for plotting raster data (mostly satellite data in tif format). I will be grateful, if I could get some advice on adding scalebar and north arrow. Any in built-functions available in this package? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The rasterVis package has a [webpage](https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis) with a [FAQ section](https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/FAQ.html), including two questions about the north arrow and the scalebar.

Comment: Many thanks, Oscar for pointing this out. I really appreciate your work on this package, which I use quite a lot. The problem here is the image is in geographic projection. I may have to modify the text and dimensions manually for showing this in kilometers, I guess. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [nice vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mapmisc/vignettes/mapmisc.pdf) to the `mapmisc` package which details some of these things. Not very aware of the rasterVis package.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I will check this package. rasterVis is a nice package and very useful for raster plotting. Worth to explore.